# Voting system with jQuery AJAX

Tags: jquery, vote

I am doing a voting system with jQuery AJAX. When clicking on a `div` (when voting), data are sent to an intermediate file (in this case `up_vote.php`), and then the div is updated with the new data. It works perfectly, giving result = 2 (variable plus one).

In a second phase, I try to present the result of the vote in another div (`#results` in another site of the page). The problem is, it refreshes the div, but the result is incorrect, showing 1 instead of 2 (looks like the variable had not been sent, or the div refreshed before receiving the result).

I leave the complete code in case anyone wants to try ...

Index.html

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />   
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="myjquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $(".n_vote").click(function() {
                var id_field = $(this).attr("id");
                var parent = $(this);

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "up_vote.php",
                    data: {
                        id_field: id_field, 
                        name: name
                    },
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(html) {
                        //Show the results in the same div
                        parent.html(html); 
                        //Show the results in another div, #results
                        $("#results").load("up_vote.php"); 
                    }  
                });
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>

    <div class="vote_system">
        <div class="n_vote" name="up" id="1">Clic here to show the result</div>
    </div>
    <!-- Correct result=2 -->
    ______________________________

    <br>
    Show the result in a another div: 
    <br>
    <div class="results" id="results">
    </div>
    <!--  Incorrect result=1 -->
</body>
</html>
```

up_vote.php

```
<?php
    $id_field = $_POST['id_field'];
    echo 'Result=';
    echo $id_field + 1;
?>
```

Can someone with more experience explain to me why the second div doesn't show the correct result? What happens and how do I solve it?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `$("#results").load("up_vote.php");` that loads up_vote.php (obviousely passing $id_field as not set and empty, because you load the url via get and no parameter) so it s normal that you got 1 instead of 2.
 you have to use the same success html returned from server to show it in the second div, like `$("#results").html(html);`